# Cannot open filestream for reading but still I am able to copy the file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-io, filestream

This line:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(src, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

throws:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'X' because
>   it is being used by another process.

When I replace the line with:

```
File.Copy(src, dst, true);
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(dst, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

it works.

But why I can copy, which surely reads the whole content of file, while being restricted from directly reading the file? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What if you use `FileShare.ReadWrite`? If another process has write access open your request will fail if you only allow shared read access.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes! But why? Oh I see...

Comment: If there is no duplicates for this question do not delete it. It is a valid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you open a file there is a check for access modes and sharing modes. The access modes of any process must be compatible with the sharing modes of others. So if A wants access to read, others must have allowed reading in sharing mode. Same for writing.

If process A has opened a file for writing and you say `SharingMode.Read` the call will fail. You are in this case saying "others may only read from the file, not write."

If you specify `ShareMode.ReadWrite` you're saying "others can read or write, I don't care" and if no other process has specified `ShareMode.Write` you are allowed to read from the file.

Answer (score 2):

> But why I can copy, which surely reads the whole content of file

Well, conceptually it reads the whole file, though it can happen at a lower level than copying streams. On Windows it's a call to the [`CopyFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx) system function, passing in the paths. On *nix systems it also uses a system call, but does open the source file with `FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read` for that call, so you would have the same issue.

> while being restricted from directly reading the file?

If a file may be written to then you cannot open it `FileShare.Read` because at some point between the various operations you are doing the file could be changed and your operations will give the wrong results.

`CopyFileEx` can succeed by preventing any writes that happen to it during the short period it was operating from affecting the results. There would be no way to offer a more general form of this, because there's no way to know you are going to close the stream of it again quickly.

> Is there a workaround?

A workaround for what? That you can't open a stream, or that you can copy the file? For the former the latter provides just such a workaround: Copy the file to get a snapshot of how it was, though note that it isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I just mistook `FileShare.Read`for `FileShare.ReadWrite` so `FileShare.ReadWrite` fixed the problem for me.